Strange error with mxnet, gluonts, and numpy
Whenever I attempt to install mxnet, I am hit with the error:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\umath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\lgaty\miniconda3\include -IC:\Users\lgaty\miniconda3\Include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\winrt /Tcnumpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.obj
      scalarapi.c
      numpy\core\include\numpy/npy_3kcompat.h(210): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\lgaty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3id6da8e\numpy_00582261eab748f08d1e565d39571542\numpy\core\src\multiarray\common.h(239): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'npy_uintp' to 'int', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\lgaty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3id6da8e\numpy_00582261eab748f08d1e565d39571542\numpy\core\src\multiarray\common.h(307): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'int', possible loss of data
      numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c(74): warning C4013: 'PyUnicode_AS_DATA' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c(74): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'void *' of greater size
      numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c(135): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'void *' of greater size
      numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c(326): warning C4013: 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c(327): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'int', possible loss of data
      numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c(565): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c(568): warning C4013: 'PyUnicode_GET_DATA_SIZE' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c(792): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
      error: Command "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\umath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\lgaty\miniconda3\include -IC:\Users\lgaty\miniconda3\Include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\winrt /Tcnumpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.obj" failed with exit status 2
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Running from numpy source directory.
     
      `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
     
        - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
        - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                            files that aren't checked into the git repo)
     
      Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
     
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have tried the following:

uninstalling numpy, and reinstalling it
downloading microsoft c++ build tools
downloading git, and running "git clean -xdf" as stated in the error.
attempting pip install mxnet-cu101==1.50 (was told by the Error traceback to do this)

No matter what I do it always returns to this error :(

Please copy-paste the full pip install output into the question, not only the last few lines. The relevant error message is likely in the lines you have omitted from the beginning.

Hello! Im trying to find the "10 lines of output" but i cant see anything. it outputs a lot of directory garbage but ill send some.

Ive read some stuff about not using anaconda/miniconda but when I dont i run into other issues with mxnet such as it stating something about bool with numpy or mxnet not having some attribute "context" EDIT: i updated the initial post with the stuff it throws at me^^

by the way, the error happens when installing numpy, it has nothing to do with mxnet, you should focus on solving the issue with numpy installation.

First of all upgrade your 'pip, setuptools and wheel' using the command python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel. Then restart the mxnet installation. If required build numpy separately, probably using condas conda install numpy

This is the relevant C compilation error: numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalarapi.c(792): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix it. Maybe a different version of cl.exe, maybe GCC instead of cl.exe, maybe a different version of numpy. Maybe conda install numpy. Maybe ask the mxnet developers how they install all this on Windows.
